# iterate through a "pseudo infinite" hash in powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, position, iteration, shift

Ok so my question's title can be a bit ambiguous, because I want to loop "infinitely" in an array, which is not the same as being stuck in an infinite loop...so here's what I mean:

consider this:

`$notes=@{1='A';2='B';3='C';4='D';5='E';6='F';7='G'};`

I want to be able to pick any items from the above list like say give me 1,3,5 (A,C,E) but if my selection goes beyond the size of the hash, then I want powershell to figure out how to shift back to the beginning of the table; Like for instance if I say I want items 5,7 and 9, then that would be E,G and B.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Please provide feedback if your question isn't fully answered yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might not be the most ideal solution, but you can always use a while loop and subtract the count of `$notes` until it is less than the count:

```
$notes=@{1='A';2='B';3='C';4='D';5='E';6='F';7='G'};

$selection2 = 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 23

foreach ($item IN $selection2) {
    while ($item -gt $notes.count ) {
        $item = $item - $notes.count
    }

    Write-Output $notes[$item]
}
```

result is:

```
G
A
B
C
F
G
B
```

Alternatively, if you start your array from 0 rather than 1, you can use modulo which is a bit simpler:

```
$notes=@{0='A';1='B';2='C';3='D';4='E';5='F';6='G'};

$selection2 = 5, 7 ,9

foreach ($item IN $selection2) {
    Write-Output $notes[$item % $notes.count]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Owain Esau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59241412/45375) is on the right track, but can be generalized:

As an aside: your `$notes` variable is a *hashtable* (`@{ ... }`), not an *array*.

```
$notes=@{ 1='A'; 2='B'; 3='C'; 4='D'; 5='E'; 6='F'; 7='G' }

# The lowest index (key) in $notes.
# All other indices (keys) are assumed to be contiguous.
$startNdx = 1

5, 7, 9 | ForEach-Object { $notes[$startNdx + ($_ - $startNdx) % $notes.Count] }
```

The above yields:

```
E
G
B
```

Explanation:

- `($_ - $startNdx) % $notes.Count` uses [`%`, the modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators), to calculate the "infinite" `0`-based *offset* of the input index (`$_`) among the set of indices.

  - For indices less than or equal to the max. index, this is identical to `$_ - $startIndex`.
  - For higher indices, it is the *remainder* of `$_ - $startIndex` divided by the number of indices / entries (`$notes.Count`), which is a number that "loops around" to express a `0`-based offset among the defined indices.
- `$startNdx +` then adds the starting index to the result, yielding the desired target index.